# winapi to retrieve the maximum configured page file size for all drives

Tags: windows, winapi

It appears that both [GlobalMemoryStatusEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366589(v=vs.85).aspx) and [GetPerformanceInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683210(v=vs.85).aspx) Windows APIs report the *current* size of the page file, but the page file can be configured (per disk) to grow up to a certain limit.
Is there an API to retrieve that limit, so that I can calculate the *maximum possible* commit size for the whole system (provided page file settings otherwise remain unchanged)?

Comment: *To calculate this value, call GetPerformanceInfo and subtract the value of CommitTotal from CommitLimit.*

Comment: *[CommitLimit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684824(v=vs.85).aspx): The current maximum number of pages that can be committed by the system without extending the paging file(s). This number **can change** if memory is added or deleted, or if pagefiles have grown, shrunk, or been added.*

Comment: Well of course it can change. The page file's size can be changed at any time. Even if you found a way to determine the current maximum size, nothing's stopping the user from increasing the maximum size. Then what? Of course this is not a real problem. The current size is all you would ever care about. And I can't think of very many reasons you would even need to worry about that.

Comment: I'm not talking about manually changing page file settings, I'm talking about the automatic growth of the page file because of memory pressure. I need to know how much the page file can grow, should there be a need for it.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be possible via WMI (COM and/or command-line):

```
wmic pagefile list /format:list
wmic pagefileset list /format:list
```

But can also be done in a platform-dependent* way by reading/parsing this registry setting:

`HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management\PagingFiles`

As described [here](https://www.petri.com/pagefile_optimization), this format is REG_MULTI_SZ (one line per page file):

```
<page-file> [<initial-size> <max-size>]
```

For example:

```
c:\pagefile.sys 1024 8192
```

In case of a system-managed page file the value would be:

```
?:\pagefile.sys
```

In case of system-managed the size is limited by the free space on the system drive (not entirely true for Hyper-V VMs).

* The registry setting appears to work at least in Windows XP, 7, 2012 and 10 (32/64-bit, PC).